# Can't replace referenced dll with newer version and access the new methods in visual studio 2015 community (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I've created a dll that I use in different projects (VS 2015 community with c#) whenever I need to access MySQL using an older version of MySQL server and connector. I downloaded the latest .NET connector (6.9.9) and created some asynchronous methods using the newly added methods like ExecuteNonQueryAsync etc. I removed the old reference from my project (to the old connector) and added the new one (to the new connector) but although I could see that this is the 6.9.9 version dll, I had no access to the new methods.

I created a test project, just to check what's going on, that referenced the new dll (6.9.9) and the new methods were accessible! So the new dll does have methods like ExecuteNonQueryAsync but changing the reference on my project wasn't enough to gain access to them. What am I missing? If it makes any difference I referenced the dlls by right clicking on "references" on the solution explorer.

Comment: Try to clean project and then build it, also you can delete the DLL from bin directory

Comment: @AbdulHadi Strangely it helped! Although it didn't help directly, I noticed that after removing the files, the program wouldn't build. It failed without any indication of error on the code. I noticed a warning though that the target .NET framework was not appropriate for the referenced dll... I changed it, and it works! Thanks...